# Displaying 1 row for each trip but a row for each guest on the trip

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I need to return a result set that returns 1 row for each trip but also one row for each guest on that trip.

Image showing what I'm getting on top and what I want to get below

[image: image showing what I'm getting on top and what I want to get below]

Comment: You want 1 row per trip and 1 row per guest? Those are contradictory

Comment: I think the solution on top is actually better, why would you want to discard the information for all guests but the first?

Comment: The output I need is labeled as 1 row per trip, per guest, I assume its to hide/not display any redundant information as all those guests would have the same trip information just different personal info.

Comment: You could create a [temporary](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-temporary-table.html) table

Comment: Typically this is something you would do while formatting the results in another package, not SQL